# How to create an installer for windows service built in C++

Tags: c++, windows-services, installation

I want to create an installer for windows service built in C++. I have followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685967%28VS.85%29.aspx) article to create the Service.
 I have 3 win32 console application in my solution. one for installation , one for uninstallation and one that does the actual work.

Comment: You mean you want the installer to be built in C++, or that you have a program which happens to be written in C++ for which you need an installer?

Comment: my program is written in c++ and i want to create an installer for that.

Comment: That's what I thought. Then WiX is the way to go :)

Comment: I know about WIX. Isn't there any other way? using Visual Studio or anything like that?

Comment: Votive is a Visual Studio plugin that's part of WiX. There is a "setup project" accessible from within VS but it's quite limited. WiX can access every feature accessible in the Windows Installer format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must humbly recommend [WiX (Windows Installer XML Toolset)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) for all your installer needs.